Problem mounting Linkstation LS210 SMB network drive in Ubuntu 24.04
I'm trying to mount my Buffalo LS210 SMB network drive in Ubuntu 24.04. There is no password set on the share,but I'm not having any luck getting it to mount successfully. I've tried several different iterations of the following and have had no luck. This mount command prompted a request for the root password for the NAS drive.
sudo mount -t cifs -o uid=xxxxxxx //192.168.1.174/share /mnt/LS210D612
Any help figuring this out would be appreciated.


There is no password set on the share,but I'm not having any luck
getting it to mount successfully.

The general syntax for a "passwordless" share is to send the "guest" option:
sudo mount -t cifs -o guest,uid=xxxxxxx //192.168.1.174/share /mnt/LS210D612

Note: NAS' tend to use antique versions of samba so you may need to pass another parameter that uses a lower dialect of smb like vers=1.0 or vers=2.0 like this:
sudo mount -t cifs -o guest,uid=xxxxxxx,vers=1.0 //192.168.1.174/share /mnt/LS210D612  

